# Total of two columns not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I want to get the total from amount where charity is 0 minus a sum of amount where charity is 1.

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) - (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                        FROM Transactions 
                       WHERE (Charity = 1))
  FROM Transactions 
 WHERE (Charity = 0)
```

This query runs but wont give me the correct results.

Comment: Sample data? Expected results? It's a little tricky to know how to correct it when we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I think I got the problem.. some values are negative some are positive, that's why the results are not as expected. how can I make all numbers to be treated as positive?

Comment: we can make it treat all values positive (by inserting an `ABS()` call around the `Amount` column) but it raises serious questions on whether the resulting calculation makes (financial) sense.

Comment: It would seem to me that making a negative number positive for the purposes of a SUM would be 'the wrong thing to do' - are you certain you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks that does the trick... Thanks a lot for all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating all values as positive:

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(Amount)) - (SELECT SUM(ABS(Amount)) 
                        FROM Transactions 
                       WHERE (Charity = 1))
  FROM Transactions 
 WHERE (Charity = 0)
```

But it seriously doubtful that negative transactions should be treated the same as positives. If there are, legitimately, negative transactions in this table, then they should probably be treated as negatives (as in your original query), or excluded:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) - (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                        FROM Transactions 
                       WHERE (Charity = 1) AND Amount > 0)
  FROM Transactions 
 WHERE (Charity = 0) AND Amount > 0
```

Not sure what facilities are available in sqlite. In standard SQL, I'd probably rewrite this as:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Charity=0 THEN Amount END),0) -
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Charity=1 THEN Amount END),0)
FROM Transactions
WHERE
    Charity in (0,1) AND
    Amount > 0
```

(Or similar transform for the `ABS` version)

Comment: One of the `SUM(CASE...)` expressions in the last query would return NULL (and so the entire result would then be NULL) in case there were rows only with `Charity=0` or only with `Charity=1` (not necessarily the OP's case, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Try if this helps.

```
select a.sum1 - b.sum2
from
(SELECT  SUM(Amount) as sum1 FROM Transactions WHERE (Charity = 0)) A,
(SELECT  SUM(Amount) as sum2 FROM Transactions WHERE (Charity = 1)) B
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below (I hope this is valid in SQLite):

```
SELECT (SELECT  SUM(Amount) FROM Transactions WHERE (Charity = 0)) - 
       (SELECT  SUM(Amount) FROM Transactions WHERE (Charity = 1))
```

Comment: So this _doesn't_ give you (total charity 0) - (total charity 1)?

Comment: plz see comment above, I think I found the problem.